# Another mysterious failure

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am getting this in the function log. Haven't seen this pattern before and don't know what it means nor how to correct it. Only change to function was to change a regex expression.

```
2017-04-01T23:45:25.431 Function completed (Failure, Id=25de0b34-b138-4390-af0c-f8f6ed68fd48)
2017-04-01T23:45:25.509 Exception while executing function: Functions.FormatEmail. mscorlib: Could not load file or assembly '0 bytes loaded from Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. Bad IL format.
2017-04-01T23:45:25.619 mscorlib: Exception while executing function: Functions.FormatEmail. mscorlib: Could not load file or assembly '0 bytes loaded from Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. Bad IL format.
2017-04-01T23:45:25.728 mscorlib: Exception while executing function: Functions.FormatEmail. mscorlib: Could not load file or assembly '0 bytes loaded from Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. Bad IL format.
2017-04-01T23:45:25.759 mscorlib: Exception while executing function: Functions.FormatEmail. mscorlib: Could not load file or assembly '0 bytes loaded from Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. Bad IL format.
2017-04-01T23:45:25.791 mscorlib: Exception while executing function: Functions.FormatEmail. mscorlib: Could not load file or assembly '0 bytes loaded from Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. Bad IL format.
2017-04-01T23:45:25.916 mscorlib: Exception while executing function: Functions.FormatEmail. mscorlib: Could not load file or assembly '0 bytes loaded from Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. Bad IL format.
2017-04-01T23:45:25.979 Function started (Id=ac8c2552-e697-4e65-bd1a-33e5b9a3b802)
2017-04-01T23:45:25.979 Function completed (Failure, Id=ac8c2552-e697-4e65-bd1a-33e5b9a3b802)
2017-04-01T23:45:26.073 mscorlib: Exception while executing function: Functions.FormatEmail. mscorlib: Could not load file or assembly '0 bytes loaded from Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. Bad IL format.
2017-04-01T23:45:26.104 Exception while executing function: Functions.FormatEmail. mscorlib: Could not load file or assembly '0 bytes loaded from Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. Bad IL format.
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be mixing 32bit and 64bit assemblies that are getting copied up to your function app. Ensure in you build configuration that you are building all the same.